# Downloading Themes for Shopify Local Development

Tags: shopify

I run this command in the terminal to pull my theme files from Shopify to my local development environment.

```
  theme get –password=your-api-password –store=your-store.myshopify.com –themeid=your-theme-id
```

Usually, this command works fine but I got a message on the terminal and I'm not sure what the next step is, it's not listed in any documentation.  The message is:

```
  Available theme versions:
  [116161183899][live] Debut
```

What's the next command to download this actual theme?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add `--list` on the command you write, this is not an error, `theme get --list --password=... --store=...` give you the list of all templates installed on your site. Your msg says you have one.

after that, you have two options use the commands get or download. I recommend you use get, because it will set a config file to easy use all the commands on the future, more info [here](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/commands/#get) with `get` the command the first time should be:

```
theme get --password=... --store=... --themeid=...
```

After that it will download the theme and create a config file on the root of the project. you can use this config file on the future with any command.

```
theme get --env=development
```

the config file is very useful, you can set multiple enviroments, [more details here](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/configuration/)

If this not fix your issue please send the version `themekit version` and OS you use.

Comment: Hi Chef, I tried that, I'm missing a step - check out this screenshot that I attached above.  I created an empty folder for this project and am running these commands so that I can download the theme contents here.  That's to explain why I don't have a config file.

Comment: `theme get --list --password=... --store=...` serve for find the theme id, after that run get without `--list` and adding `--themeid` the final command first time is  `theme get --password=... --store=... --themeid=...`